# Sscanf и разбор GET запроса

Tags: c, get, arduino

Не могу найти доходчивого мануала, а соответственно блуждаю в темноте. С сайта на arduino nano приходит вот такой запрос

```
+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=XXXXXXX&pass=CCCCCCCC&room=SSSSSSS HTTP/1.1
```

Как используя Sscanf разбить его на переменные ssid,pass,room?

Имеем работающий вариант:

```
    char* s = "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=text_one&pass=text_two&room=text_three HTTP/1.1";

    char ssid[32] = {};
    char pass[32] = {};
    char room[32] = {};

    sscanf(s, "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=%[^&]&pass=%[^&]&room=%s HTTP/1.1", ssid, pass, room);

    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.println(pass);
    Serial.println(room);
```

Если теперь в `sscanf` убрать `+IPD,1,480:` то функция перестает работать

Comment: А хочется именно sscanf? strpos + strtok уже проходит?

Comment: Да все равно. Суть в том что c esp8266 прилетают данные и пишутся в char. Вот надо оттуда вытянуть эти переменные

Comment: `все сломалось` это совершенно бесполезное определение. Для начала уберите `&` перед переменными в `sscanf`.

Comment: Убрал. Вот вывод`+IPD find
submit find
+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=text_one&pass=text_two&room=text_three HTTP/1.1

` И все

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин я ничего не понял, если честно. Добавляйте важную для решения задачи информацию прямо в текст вопроса, а не в комментарий. Попробуйте привести [mcve].

Comment: Используйте [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) для поиска подстроки, например `submit?`. И в `sscanf` вместо `s` подставляйте результат возврата `strstr`.

Comment: Скажите а почему не отрабатывает `sscanf(s, "+IPD,%d,%d:GET /submit?ssid=%[^&]&pass=%[^&]&room=%s HTTP/1.1", id,len,ssid, pass, room);`

Comment: @alexolut Вот спасибо тебе огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сложного:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* s = "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=1111111&pass=22222222&room=3333333 HTTP/1.1";

    int ssid = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    int room = 0;

    sscanf(s, "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=%d&pass=%d&room=%d HTTP/1.1", &ssid, &pass, &room);

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", ssid, pass, room);
}
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wSxm9aNmoHZ0Hj5V)</kbd>

Для строковых аргументов можно использовать такой вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* s = "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=text_one&pass=text_two&room=text_three HTTP/1.1";

    char ssid[20] = {};
    char pass[20] = {};
    char room[20] = {};

    sscanf(s, "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=%[^&]&pass=%[^&]&room=%s HTTP/1.1", ssid, pass, room);

    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", ssid, pass, room);
}
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g93rQbTvQoEfFLMT)</kbd>

Comment: А если не int  а char?

Comment: @ВарфаламейИзольдин а, так у Вас там строки?

Comment: А если параметры вдруг местами поменяются или новый в середине будет?:)

Comment: @KoVadim надо исходить из текущей задачи :) Будут изменения, будем думать дальше.

Comment: Нет параметров новых не будет и местами они меняться не будут. ESP если не находит ssid и pass у себя в памяти становиться точкой доступа и выдает вэб морду с полями.

Comment: Кажется ваш вариант сработал. Странно нечто похожее я уже писал и он выдавал мне не то что надо

Comment: О! [Действительно рабоатет](http://ideone.com/mGoVFZ). А я-то думал, что оно не так)) [Перечитал](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Comment: А может кто то объяснить почему при добавлении  в loop двух sscanf дуина компилировать не хочет?collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Qwertiy что-то не так?

Comment: @alexolut, наоборот, всё так. Я почему-то думал, что текст в scanf работает как `%*[...]`, а оказалось, он всё в точности проверяет, кроме пробельных.

Answer (score 2):

Вот Вам заготовка с комментариями:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h> 

int main(void) {
    char orig[] = "+IPD,1,480:GET /submit?ssid=XXXXXXX&pass=CCCCCCCC&room=SSSSSSS HTTP/1.1";
    char * s = strdup(orig); // сделаем копию, так как строку будем модифицировать
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok(s, "?");
    if (pch == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (1) {
        char * key = strtok(NULL, "?=& ");
        char * param = strtok(NULL, "?=& ");
        if (key == NULL || param == NULL)
            break;
        printf("%s => %s\n", key, param);
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```